# How is $\dfrac{4x}{x-3}$ equal to $4+\dfrac {12}{x-3}$?

Tags: simple-functions

I am told that $\dfrac{4x}{x-3}$ is equal to $4+\dfrac {12}{x-3}$, but I have no idea how to arrive at that.

Can anyone, please, break it up for me?

Comment: $\frac{4(x-3)+12}{x-3}$

Comment: Because this question prompted the correct answer which at 1st glance is slightly surprising, it is by definition a good question.  It would have been better for the question-asker to show where his/her attempt resulted in an obstacle or something perplexing though.

Answer (score 4):

\begin{equation*}
4+\frac{12}{x-3}=\frac{4(x-3)}{x-3}+\frac{12}{x-3}=\frac{4x-12+12}{x-3}=\frac{4x}{x-3}
\end{equation*}